# Cross-platform protobuffers, deserializing with Protobuf-net and inheritence

Tags: c#, go, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Forgive, in advance, any ignorance regarding protobuffers or Go, as both of these technologies are relatively new to me.

We've been using protobuffers and protobuf-net in production for a little while. We use Redis as a message queue between systems, and everything that reads or writes to Redis uses the exact same models (a shared library) and protobuf-net to serialize and deserialize. Now, however, we want to push things into Redis from a system written in Go. My problem is that the Go-written protobuffer data is not able to be deserialized in my .NET application with protobuf-net

See the following small example for my problem.

I am using protoc version 2.6.1 for the Golang approach and protobuf-net version 2.0.0.668 for .NET

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(3, typeof(SomeDerivedClass))]
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Int32 Foo { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class SomeDerivedClass : BaseClass
{

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public String Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Using `Serializer.GetProto<SomeDerivedClass>();` yields the following .proto file:

```
message BaseClass {
   optional int32 Foo = 1 [default = 0];
   // the following represent sub-types; at most 1 should have a value
   optional SomeDerivedClass SomeDerivedClass = 3;
}
message SomeDerivedClass {
   optional string Bar = 2;
}
```

Which, using protogen, yielded the following .go file:
https://gist.github.com/cjqed/408dd9fd11e935239f36

Then,

```
derived := &SomeDerivedClass{
    Bar: proto.String("h"),
}
baseClass := &BaseClass{
    SomeDerivedClass: derived,
    Foo: proto.Int32(13),
} 
data, err := proto.Marshal(baseClass)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

When deserialized with protobuf-net, results in

Result: `ProtoException, No parameterless constructor found for BaseClass`

...Unless I make BaseClass non-abstract. Which, although possible, is not really a good solution.

Finally, I made the exact same object in protobuf-net and in Go (both on the same machine, mind you), and these are the bytes for each:

(Code in protobuf-net to serialize)

```
var obj = new SomeDerivedClass
{
    Bar = "h",
    Foo = 13
};
byte[] data;

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    Serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, obj);
    data = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

Protobuf-net:
`26, 3, 18, 1, 104, 8, 13`

With github.com/golang/protobuf/proto:
`8, 13, 26, 3, 18, 1, 104`

Note the last two bytes in protobuf-net are the first two in golang.

So, am I doing something wrong, or is there a bug in one of the two protobuffer libraries? Or maybe in the go protogen?

Comment: Which version of protobuf-net are you using?

Comment: yes i guess the version problem.

Comment: protobuf doesn't support inheritance

Comment: show us the code that you use to serialize the data using protobuf-net

Comment: @isim The go code is using 2.6.1. I'm not sure what version of protobuffers the latest nuget package of protobuf-net is using, I believe it's baked into the DLL you get down from nuget.

Comment: @kostya I mean, protobuf-net to protobuf-net understands inheritance, so there has to be some way for the golang version to serialize that information right? Unless protobuf-net is just using a custom protocol on top of protobuffers, which I suppose is possible. But when why, if I make my base class non-abstract, does everything work fine?

I added version numbers and code for protobuf-net serialization to the question.

Comment: So you are saying that everything works as expected if you make the base class non-abstract? Is it correct? It looks like protobuf-net doesn't support inheritance with abstract classes.

Comment: Yeah, everything works as expected if I make the base class non-abstract. However, I can use the abstract base class if I serialize with protobuf-net, and it deserializes it with no issues at all. It's when I serialize it with protoc in golang that it's failing. I feel like the issue might have to do with how protobuf-net is seeing the inheritance tree, it looks like with the protobuf-net serialized version it understands that I want an object of type SomeDerivedType... but if it's golang serialized, it's creating the BaseClass first, then marshaling it into SomeDerivedClass.

Comment: I still beleive it is protobuf-net limitation. Go implementation serializes data according to the spec. However protobuf-net treats the spec loosely. See this answer by protobuf-net creator (the last paragraph): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808290/order-of-deserialization-in-protobuf-net.